# Xamarin - Android App Development - Switch icon is missing and causing NullPointer

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

For my business, another developer and myself are working on a mobile text and speech app. We would like to add a bunch of switch widgets to our one page as a Settings page. However, When I run it on the debugger emulator, I get a Null Pointer Error with no information of what the problem was. We were able to determine it was the symbol not being available because my fellow developer ran the same code, got the text to show, but the symbol still was not showing. However he did not get the same error.

To further test, I created a blank project, added a Switch to the same style layout, and ran it with no problems.

I am only adding the switch in the XML of the layout.

Is there a way I can repair/add back in the image to remove the null pointer? Thanks!

Edit: One error log I am receiving:

```
W/dalvikvm( 1965): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception(group=0xa8cbbb20)
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.NullPointerException:

06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965): Process: SecureMobileApp.Droid, PID: 1965
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.widget.Switch.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(Switch.java:825)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5488)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5488)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(FrameLayout.java:189)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5488)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5488)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(FrameLayout.java:189)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5488)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5488)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(FrameLayout.java:189)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.View.onAttachedToWindow(View.java:12116)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.onAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onAttachedToWindow(PhoneWindow.java:2659)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12585)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2458)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1213)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-27 16:49:39.449 E/AndroidRuntime( 1965):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you add relevant code snippets, error logs, and things that you've tried to your post? Ideally it sounds like you simply aren't setting something and it's coming out as a NRE.

Comment: a switch *statement* is a C# construct; a Switch *widget* is an Android UI control.  I assume you mean the latter, but your question specifically says "statement"

Comment: yep sorry Jason, thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the problem if anyone runs into the same problem. I am working with a team and one of the other developers had changed the minimum SDK, it was at Level 15, but had been changed to Level 4. You need at least a Level 14 minimum SDK to use a switch widget.